# Auto-correct in all applications in Ubuntu

Tags: 15.04

Windows 8.1 has nice feature that autocorrect mistyped words in all applications. Is it possible to implement that function in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu uses a package called `aspell` to indicate the mistyped but it doesn't provide  autocorrect.

```
man aspell
```

> aspell is a utility program that connects to the Aspell library so
>   that
>          it can function as an ispell -a replacement, as  an  independent  spell
>          checker,  as a test utility to test out Aspell library features, and as
>          a utility for managing dictionaries used by the library.
>
> ```
>    The Aspell library contains an interface allowing other programs direct
>    access  to  its  functions  and  therefore reducing the complex task of
>    spell checking to simple library calls.  The default library  does  not
>    contain  dictionary  word  lists.  To add language dictionaries
> ```

**But you have to notice** that some apps are using aspell common dictionary such as Evolution, Abiword .... While some others use their own dictionary, such as LibreOffice, which uses `libreoffice-l10n-[language code]` and `language-support-writing-[language code]` packages.

To install a language dictionary

```
sudo apt-get install aspell-[lan code]
```

For example to install Spanish dictionary

```
sudo apt-get install aspell-es
```

Comment: It's only working for applications that have compiled with aspell and this this not autocorrect. Its only indicate mistyped words.

Comment: @QkiZ Thanks for your note, I had to mentioned that before. Added.